# Extra in-line CSS on all DIVs marked as !Important that breaks the site (sets minimum size to 0), cannot find its source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, all of a sudden, a site I maintain (built with Bootstrap and JQuery), nothing special, HTML, not PHP, stopped looking properly.

It has a side-panel and now that whole side-panel appears for a few seconds when I reload the page then it disappears and leaves a white placeholder.

I tracked the problem down to the fact that the DIV that contains the sidebar gets an in-line style attribute containing `height: auto !important; min-height: 0px !important;`. Not sure why, as the original source code does not have any attributes. Removing this with the Chrome HTML Inspect Element fixes the site.

What I have tried:

- Tried downloading the whole source to run it locally on my Mac. Since it's HTML. It works as it should when loaded locally.
- Disabled CloudFlare, flushed the caches and tried in Incognito with all extensions off. Same thing.
- Tried adding myself an inline style to that div so that it would prevent changes. It didn't. The `height: auto !important; min-height: 0px !important;` gets added after my existing in-line rules.
- Tried Checking my JavaScript for anything that would add that. I wasn't able to find anything.
- Tried to load the site on a new installation of a different browser (FireFox). Same.

Does anybody have any idea where those rules come from? The same rules get added to all DIVS on the page but it only affects the sidebar from what I can tell.

I did have an error message about `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function` which seems to be fixable by adding the latest Jquery and Bootstrap (I use older versions on the site).

Please keep in mind that the site worked fine a month or so ago and I haven't done any changes since.

EDIT: It seems that the issue is Adsense injecting that style tag, but I cannot tell why. Someone else complained about a similar incident but with no real answer other than hooking what Adsense does and undoing in in Javascript

Comment: I would like to mention that I am not very skilled with HTML, I am usually programming in C / C++ or C#.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing a live demo of the issue

Comment: The website can be checked at http://icloudbypass.fce365.info

Comment: this change is coming from the following js: `pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190918/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js` are you familiar with it? if you block this js in dev tools (or disable js completely) all will be ok

Comment: That is Google Adsense? And why does it change my website all of a sudden?

Comment: Dont know, looks like you are not alone: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695667/adsense-injecting-style-tag-into-my-page-in-chrome

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the name "wrapper" of the DIV. Changed it to "Wrapper-ID" and the code doesn't add the rules anymore. Weird.

Comment: Damn, that is weird.